# How to make registration endpoint public in nodeJS with autentication middleware

Tags: node.js, authentication, middleware

I have set up jwt token based authentication and authorization in my nodejs app, however since I am globally using the middleware, I am not able to register. I want to make that particular route public, however, I don't know how.

this is in my user.controller

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const user = await userService.register(req.body);
    if (user) {
        res.status(201).send(
            {
                success: true,
                name: user.name,
                lastName: user.lastName,
            });
    } else {
        res.status(400).send({error: err.message});
    }

});
```

This is my authentication middleware

```
const authenticate = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (!authHeader) {
        res.status(401).send({
            status: 'fail',
            message: 'Unauthorized!',
        });
    } else {
        const token = authHeader ? authHeader.split(' ')[1] : null;
        if (!token || !jwt.verify(token, configuration.secret)) {
            res.status(401).send({
                status: 'fail',
                message: 'Unauthorized',
            });
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }
}
```

And I use this in my app.js file

```
app.use(authenticate);
```